# Released app crashes several days after install

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have developed an app and have it successfully released on App Store. I have downloaded it from the App Store onto my device. At first everything worked perfectly, until after a few days, when some parts of (not all of) the app stops working properly, specifically, the device returns to its home screen when certain buttons are clicked.I have received reports from users about this issue as well.

After using XCode to build and run the app on my device, everything goes back to normal. Since this only happens after several days have passed, I cannot recreate this problem right now, hence apologies for not having error messages to show. Any ideas on possible reasons of this issue?

Comment: Problems of this sort are hard to find. As you are not specific, I will resort to generalities as well. You need to isolate it. Put debugging messages in place. Run memory profiles as invalid memory accesses are very common mistakes. Re-visit your code and design and think about its structure again and again.

Comment: Do you have code branches dependent on time passed? Do you have code branches dependent on flags set in `UserDefaults`/keychain? Did you setup your external libraries correctly for production (i.e. changed access keys and similar, where required)? Do you create and read any files? To sum up - you should, quite obviously, check all parts of your code that have to do with any sort of data persistency and/or time counting.